# Are .NET memcache libraries production ready?

Tags: c#, .net, memcached

Seeing all the UNIX guys have memcache (PHP, Python, etc.), are the .NET libraries stress tested and equally efficient? (or more?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider Microsoft's [Velocity cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476429/how-to-design-an-asp-net-mvc-site-for-caching-with-velocity). It'll probably be the one that gets the largest support and stress testing.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is still in Cummunity technical preview (CTP).  But I would agree that it's the right technology for people to evaluate from Microsoft for this purpose.

Also, just so it's considered - if you're already using memcached in your environement there is a client library for C# - [memcacheddotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/).

I used the memcached client a while back (before rejoining Microsoft) only for testing and not in production - it held up great under a simulated load of my system for 50+ concurrent user testing (which met my requirements) - never went to produciton with it though (timing didn't work out and wasn't strictly needed to satisfy anything business critical at the time).